# Set selection for edit text in data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-edittext

I have to move a cursor in the end of word in an editText. For this task I use fun `Fragment.moveCursorToEnd(editText: EditText) = editText.setSelection(editText.text.length)`
But when I need to use this method, because the text via model of DataBinding settings not right away, because I set my model in `onCreateView` , but I checked content of edit text in `onViewCreated`, `onStart` and `onResume` method of fragment and everywhere I don't get my text.
For solving this problem I can use `onTextChanged` and call method `moveCursorToEnd()` here, but may be there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to write own `BindingAdapter`.

Here documentation about [BindingAdapters](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) and if you need [Two way data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way) also.

Example **Kotlin**,

layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    app:cursorPosition="@{viewmodel.cursorPosition}"/>
```

binding adapter:

```
object EditTextBindingAdapters {
   @BindingAdapter("cursorPosition")
   fun setCursorPosition(editText: EditText, cursorPosition: Int) {
       editText.setSelection(cursorPosition)
   }
}
```

viewmodel:

```
class ViewModel : BaseObservable {
    // text is observable field
    @Bindable
    fun getCursorPosition(): Int {
        return text.length
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for text with length more then 0. It calls `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (3 ... 3) ends beyond length 0`

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin

Create a BindingAdapters file and and this static method inside.

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
fun setStringWithSelection(view: EditText, str : String?) {
    // Important to break potential infinite loops.
    if(view.text.toString() != str){
        view.setText(str)
        view.setSelection(view.text.length)
    }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way